# Set a minimum date for date field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

My model looks like this

```
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime BookingStartDate { get; set; }
```

This is from the View (Create)

```
<input asp-for="BookingStartDate" min="@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")" asp-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}" class="form-control" />
```

When I enter the date '29/09/2022, the warning still say:

```
Please enter a value greater than or equal to 27/09/2022 20:31.
```

[image]

Whats wrong here. Can you point a way to do this using Javascript?

Comment: Use date to begin at midnight : min="@DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")

Comment: now the warning say : Please enter a value greater than or equal to 27/09/2022 00:00.

Comment: Then it is probably a timezone issue.  The timezone for the min and the timezone for the textbox is different.

Comment: @jdweng: A timezone can not be more than 23 hours different.

Comment: @PoulBak : But it can be -2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Let me quote:

> **min**
> The earliest date and time to accept; timestamps earlier than this
> will cause the element to fail constraint validation. If the value of
> the min attribute isn't a valid string which follows the format
> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm, then the element has no minimum value.
>
> This value must specify a date string earlier than or equal to the one
> specified by the max attribute.

**Note the format: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm`**

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by adding the type="datetime-local", min, and max value.

```
<input required type="datetime-local" asp-for="BookingStartDate" 
  min="@DateTime.Now.AddDays(+1).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd" + "T08:30")" 
  max="2025-12-30T16:30" 
  value="@DateTime.Now.AddDays(+2).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd" + "T09:00")"
  />
```

Comment: nice, good for you :-)